# QT email client using IMAP4

Tags: qt, imap

I am developing a QT program that will check for new mails from gmail and download them using IMAP4 protocol. I am unable to write a command to display the messages in my inbox. please help me. Here is a sample of my code.

```
    socket->connectToHostEncrypted("imap.gmail.com", 993);

    if(!socket->waitForConnected(50000)){
        qDebug()<<"Error:"<<socket->errorString();
    }
}

void MySocket::connected(){
    qDebug()<<"**********\nconnected....\n*********";

    QByteArray byteArray("a001 LOGIN username password");
    socket->write(byteArray);
    socket->write("\r\n");

    socket->waitForReadyRead();

    byteArray.clear();
    byteArray.append("A002 LIST inbox");
    socket->write(byteArray);
    socket->write("\r\n");

}
```

Comment: The LIST command lists mailboxes. It does not list the contents of a particular mailbox. I suggest that you first play around with IMAP interactively using a command such as "openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf" and when you know how to read mail, you write a program to do so. You may find RFC3501 or the kmail source helpful.

Comment: Beside that it is too broad, I am wondering if you are having any copyrights infringement with your icon towards the Qt project. Have you double checked that with Digia, etc? We had some trouble slightly modifying it back then, and it seem you do not seem to use the "vanilla" logo either. Oh, and the project is called `Qt` (Q toolkit) rather than `QT` (Quick Time) as per also your logo.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously not familiar with the IMAP protocol, so you will need to read [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) if you want to be able to work with the protocol effectively.

I also suggest you check out my blog post [IMAP: Downloading emails](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/08/imap-downloading-emails.html) to get up and running quickly.

The LIST command will list the folders in your account. What you need to download emails in a folder or view their metadata is the [FETCH Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5). Again, read the RFC to learn what it offers. It is normally expected that you've done your research before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not saying I disagree, but it feels like comment material rather than answer. The question will probably be closed (and deleted?) soon, I have the impression.

Comment: You are absolutely right - this was just to point the author in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Writing an IMAP client is far from trivial. Have you considered using some existing IMAP library that is written with Qt? I can of course recommend the code from [Trojitá](http://trojita.flaska.net/), or the KDE's IMAP code.

Comment: Not saying I disagree, but it feels like comment material rather than answer. The question will probably be closed (and deleted?) soon, I have the impression.